# Bootstrap min-height

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Well, this is absolute novice question: How on earth bootstrap does not have min-height?

```
<div class="min-vh-100">
    <div class="min-heigh-75">There is no min height</div>
    <div class="min-vh-25">There is no min-vh-25 to 75</div>
</div>
```

Using h-75 and h-25 does not work as they translate to height:75% and not min-height:75%

Am I missing something here?

This is my first time I use Bootstrap. And the problem I am facing, the text within <main> overflows. Its height does not increase to push <footer> down and the reason is bootstrap .h-25 translates to css height:25%. And height:25% remains the same no matter how much its content overflows. It does not flex itself.

```
<body class="h-100"> <!-- If I use min-vh-100 then h-25 does not work -->
    <header>Header here</header>
    <main class="h-25">
        Lorem ipsum overflows the main block once it fill 25% of the parent size.
        I would like the main block to increase size once it fully filled.
    </main>
    <footer>Footer here</footer>
</body>
```

Is there any Bootstrap solution for it?

Comment: Using bootstrap does not mean that you don't need to use CSS, using CSS is necessary in many situations. So try to fix it with CSS.

Comment: ^ Not strictly. Add CSS for eye candy and display and visuals as much as you want, there is no end to it. The more CSS you add with regard to technical page layout the more chance you have of messing Bootstrap around quite a lot and creating problems that shouldn't exist.

Comment: @Aaron Hamid is sort of correct. But not to add CSS, maybe you have some CSS that is affecting the overflow and it needs to be removed.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, I guess CSS is a must. But I think I use Bootstrap to its highest as @CuteCodeRob said and include CSS for modification.

Comment: Additional CSS is always needed @Aaron for sure. It just has to be used very delicately when it comes to layout. The reason I mention it is because usually in Bootstrap I never ever have to use any kind of `v` or `h` instruction and the regular layout is always fine. This is why I think maybe there must be something affecting your overflow that needs to be removed.

Comment: Thanks @CuteCodeRob. I realised the same. I think I went wrong somewhere with my design. For now I just patched it so it can work. Next revision I will investigate to what I did wrong that this issue raised. Well, the difficult part of learning is always the start of it. LOL.
Thanks for your support, mate.